# Custom listview item in ListViewDragginganimation

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

So I have an android project where I have good use for a sorting functionality. I've been using `DevBytes` `ListViewDraggingAnimation` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q

I have gotten it to work in my app and layout, but one big issue still remains, I cannot get it to work with my custom `ListView` items. The stock item in `DevBytes` code is a plain `TextView` as such:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_size"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:textColor="#000000"
/>
```

My custom `ListView` items consist of a `RelativeLayout` with four `TextView`s inside. As such:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="adress"
        android:id="@+id/item_adressView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_driveTypeView"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="postnr, ort"
        android:id="@+id/item_zipcodePlaceView"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_adressView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_driveTypeView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="företag"
        android:id="@+id/item_companyView"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_zipcodePlaceView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_driveTypeView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="P1"
        android:id="@+id/item_driveTypeView"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Admittedly, I don't understand the data structure well. Every attempt I've made at changing it to accept my items has crashed the program. I fear I have changed more parts of the code than needed in some attempts. Could someone help me point out what parts of the code I have to change in order to get the `ListView` to accept my custom items?

Posting all java code will make my post exceed the character limit.

The code can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip

Comment: `Every attempt I've made at changing it to accept my items has crashed the program` - post the exception you get from Logcat

Comment: I have not kept all the exceptions, I guess because I have never been anywhere near the idea that I'm doing it correctly. Referencing a textview inside a relativelayout instead of a plain textview in the code generates the following (though I doubt that will be much help):

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
[LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found

Comment: I know this project well since I implemented it. For now, the easiest thing you can do is have only one TextView UI in your custom layout. The reason is StableArrayAdapter has only one method to accept textview UI only. Look at code StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId...). This is the reason why. Perhaps later I'll post an answer.

Comment: An in-depth answer would be highly appreciated The Original Android. 

Do you mean that it only accepts one string per item on the listview? I want to be able to have an item of different size texts for example.

Comment: I m surprise that you got error "java.lang.ClassCastException". I know you changed your layout. Did u change any Java code in the ListViewDraggingAnimation app?

Comment: Yes, when I referenced a custom itemview(the relativelayout with textviews). 

Honestly I don't think the exceptions are to much help. I tried around 10 different things, all completely different from eachother and probably all just as wrong. I'm too aware of how lost I am to feel comfortable in relying on the exceptions I got.

At this point I'm just hoping someone will guide me through how to correctly change the project so that I can use my own itemviews

Comment: Pls just post the changed code. It does help to see the errors/exceptions with the related code. I have helped many others by isolating problems. Sometimes I can guess what the problem is but then sometimes not. You may post the Logcat errors in the original posted question. the logcat shows line numbers and the filenames.

Comment: I discarded all code from the attempts since I don't really think I was going anywhere with any of them.

I've been building at other parts of the project while waiting for an answer here, because truthfully, I am completely lost. I can make new attempts just to have something to post, but they would be complete stabs in the dark.

Comment: I posted an answer based on your responses. And the comments here are getting too much.

Comment: You have to change your adapter if you want to use complex row layouts. The DevBytes example only provides a simple adapter that uses a single textview row. Change your adapter if you want accept more complex layouts. You can modify adapater's constructor from the provided example to make it accept a layout id, with which you can further bind data to other views by overriding getView().

Comment: If someone could help me with a code example of that I would be so grateful

I'm not sure I know how to change that adapter without making glaring errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the adapter if you want to bind data to multiple views (besides just a simple TextView). Read the [ArrayAdapter reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to understand how these adapter works.

Basically, your constructor needs to take in your complex data structure, then you need to override getView() to bind data to multiple views. Using the DevBytes example, try something like this:

```
// Update the adapter to use string arrays instead of just strings
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {

    final int INVALID_ID = -1;
    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Save these references to the layout and string data
    int mRowLayout;
    List<String[]> mStrings;

    // Constructor should accept string arrays
    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int rowLayout, List<String[]> objects) {

        super(context, rowLayout, objects);

        // Change this so your string array list can be indexed
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {

            // Make sure you are using a unique string for each list row
            // String[0] is just an example
            String[] stringArray = objects.get(i);
            String uniqueString = stringArray[0]; 

            mIdMap.put(uniqueString, i);
        }

        mRowLayout = rowLayout;
        mStrings = objects;
    }

    ...

    // Populate your layout text views with data from your string array
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mRowLayout, null);

        TextView tvAddress = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_adressView);
        TextView tvZipCode = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_zipcodePlaceView);
        TextView tvCompany = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_companyView);
        TextView tvDriveType = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_driveTypeView);

        tvAddress.setText(mStrings.get(position)[0]);
        tvZipCode.setText(mStrings.get(position)[1]);
        tvCompany.setText(mStrings.get(position)[2]);
        tvDriveType.setText(mStrings.get(position)[3]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In your activity, just load the adapter with your layout xml file and string arrays, like this:

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, mStringsList);
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work. I used something similar recently. Also, you can find several tutorials on the internet for how to make custom adapters. Here's a good one to check out: [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Answer (score 0):

First let's debug the current issue and hope to fix the runtime error "**java.lang.ClassCastException**: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView".

Using your design, make only 1 Textview UI in the layout like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="adress"
        android:id="@+id/item_adressView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_driveTypeView"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Good luck...

**EDIT1**: In the logcat messages:

com.example.android.listviewdragginganimation E/ArrayAdapter﹕ 
 You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

com.example.android.listviewdragginganimation 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.android.listviewdragginganimation, PID: 1830

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView 
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
 ...

**Notes**:

- The biggest hint is "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView...". In your layout, simply supply only 1 TextView for now. I already gave one example above. Try it out and see what happens.
- After this fix, you can add more TextView in the layout. But you must specify a specific Textview .

Comment: Wasnt sure what exactly to post, this is all the error messages I get when I change try what you just posted without changing code:

http://pastebin.com/D0iLuCXv

I want to keep stressing though that I don't even know where to start, so whatever I'm doing wrong is not a typo or simple mistake.

Comment: @Flowdorio, Thanks for the logcat post. I added "EDIT1" in my post, try it out. I hope there will be progress with this fix. Otherwise I cannot help you anymore. If you think my answer is at least helpful, you may click on the useful icon (up-arrow) ;) Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party library which does this for you, just need to undersatnd that and implement in a way we want, just try [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) before trying anything else.